# Copy constructor help, trying to copy a boolean array. Java

Tags: java, arrays, copy-constructor

I have looked through as many previous questions as possible but never saw a question that had a boolean array as a variable.

Here is my class:

```
public class Register {

private boolean[] register;
private int length;

    //Normal constructor
public Register(int n) {

    if (n == 8 || n == 16 || n == 32 || n == 64) {

        length = n;
        register = new boolean[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

            register[i] = false;
        }

    } else {

        throw new RegisterException(
                "A register can only contain 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits");
    }

}

// Creates a copy of reg (an existing Register)
public Register(Register reg) {

    length = reg.length;
    register = new boolean[reg.register.length];

    System.arraycopy(reg.register, 0, this.register, 0, reg.register.length);
}
```

In my driver program i am loading "1101101" into register1, but when i do:
Register register2 = new Register(register1);

and print out both results i get:

0000000001101101

0000000000010110

Not really sure what is going on O.o any help would be appreciated, thanks!

This is my load method. i held off on putting it in here because it might be hard to read:

```
public void load(String binaryRep) {

    String allTheBits = binaryRep;
    int charPosition = 0;
    int loadLength;
    int binaryNum = 0;
    String index = "";
    String trimmedIndex = "";

    if (allTheBits.length() > 0 && allTheBits.length() <= length) {

        loadLength = allTheBits.length();

        for (int i = length - (loadLength); i < length; i++) {

            index = allTheBits.charAt(charPosition) + "";
            trimmedIndex = index.trim();
            binaryNum = Integer.parseInt(trimmedIndex);

            if (binaryNum == 1) {

                register[i] = true;

            } else if (binaryNum == 0) {

                register[i] = false;
            }

            charPosition++;

        }
    } else {
        throw new RegisterException("You can only load 0 - " + length
                + "bits.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code for printing? As an aside, you don't need to explicitly initialize the elements of `register` to `false` in the default constructor; that's the default value for new array allocations. Also, since `this.register.length == this.length` for each Register object, you don't really need the `length` field.

Comment: 8 bits but you only have 7 digit numbers? is there something missing?

Comment: @Tim: you didn't paste the code where you "load" the register with "1101101".  I'm pretty sure you have some logic inversed in your "load" method.

Comment: @Tim: btw there's probably not many reasons yet for you to use your own *RegisterException* at this point (seen the basic question you are asking, I wouldn't advice creating your own exceptions at this point... And later on you may very well decide that custom exception aren't exactly that useful in a great many languages where they don't even exist at all and that, even in Java, you can do without them).  *An IllegalArgumentException* is probably what your after.

Comment: i posted my load method. thanks for the other tips though guys, appreciate it. since i posted my load method i posted what the actual output is. we're supposed to load them starting from the back. thought it would be easier to read the other way

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your load method, at least with how it is used with your constructors. Therefore the problem lies with the way you access and print the values.

Comment: @prusswan *rolls eyes* of course i could get the hard stuff right but the simple stuff wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a more idiomatic way of doing it (using the Cloneable interface):

```
public class Register implements Cloneable {

private boolean[] register;

public Register(boolean[] register) {

    int n = register.length;

    if (n == 8 || n == 16 || n == 32 || n == 64) {
        this.register = register;
    } else {

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "A register can only contain 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits");
    }

}

@Override
public String toString() {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for ( boolean b : this.register ) {
        builder.append( b ? "1" : "0" );
    }

    return builder.toString();
}

public Register( int n ) {
    this( new boolean[n] );
}

public int getLength() {
    return this.register.length;
}

@Override
public Register clone() {

    boolean[] clonedRegister = new boolean[this.register.length];

    System.arraycopy(this.register, 0, clonedRegister,0, this.register.length);

    return new Register( clonedRegister );
}

}
```

And a JUnit test showing it in action:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;


public class RegisterTest {

    @Test
    public void testRegisterToString() {

        Register source = new Register( new boolean[] {true, true, false, false, true, false, true, false } );

        String result = "11001010";

        Assert.assertEquals( result, source.toString() );

    }

    @Test
    public void testRegisterCloning() {

        Register source = new Register( new boolean[] {true, true, false, false, true, false, false, false } );
        Register clone = source.clone();

        Assert.assertEquals( source.toString(), clone.toString() );

    }

}
```

Comment: Nice code. It just needs the copy constructor that was the subject of OP's original post. :)

Comment: i need to use a constructor though >.> thank you for the answer though it really helps me understand my own program even better.

Comment: It's bad design to have a copy constructor when the language itself defines a Cloneable interface and asks people to implement it when the "cloning" pattern is necessary :)

Comment: @Tim: I've 1+'d (up-voted) this answer as it is a decent effort at providing you with a solution. I recommend that you do likewise, even if you don't ultimately select it as the solution.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full of Eels I've tried, but i need 15 rep to do so

Comment: @Tim: I've used my last vote of the day and have up-voted the original question. Tim, you now have enough rep to up-vote up to your daily maximum, congrats! :)

Comment: @Maurício Linhares Well that'd be true if the clone interface in Java wasn't completely broken (heck even its own developers/designers say they don't use it). So having a copy constructor isn't bad design - lots of official classes have one (while almost nothing implements clonable). Still +1 since it shows good code and can easily be converted :)

Answer (score 3):

A couple of remarks so that you learn some basic things.

1. As @Ted said, no need to keep the length field as register. length will give you the same
2. Local variables are not initialized with default values, but arrays are, as they are stored in the heap. So there's no need to iterate over the "register" array to set all of its positions to false
3. Using an array of booleans to do this may have felt easy but its extremely inefficient memory wise, as each boolean takes at least 32 bits in the heap. Therefore, to represent a 64 bit register you are using at least 32*64+32=2080 bits... using a byte array and bitwise logic will be a bit harder but hey, it's a small challenge :)

Anyway, your code looks fine (BTW, use Arrays.copyOf method as it's more readable), so the error should be coming from another side.

Comment: Yes Ted, you're right, a BitSet will do just fine. I was forgetting about that class. So @Tim, you don't even have to redo the wheel :)

Answer (score 2):

I just verified your load method with the following:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Register r1 = new Register(8);
    r1.load("1101101");
    Register r2 = new Register(r1);
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) System.out.println(r2.register[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
> run Register
false
true
true
false
true
true
false
true
>
```

It looks right to me as far as the contents of the Register objects are concerned, so the problem probably is with the access.